# using plural nouns with plural nouns?

Tags: grammaticality

I wanted to say "Please take a look at the ones with *check marks* beside them". But I was kind of confused whether it is more correct to say "Please take a look at the ones with *a check mark* beside them".

Also, would "I've attached *the copies* of the photos" be more correct than "I've attached *a copy* of the photos"?

**EDIT:**
Sorry for recycling old questions, but I didn't want to start a new topic...

Can I say "Please find attached **the copies of A, B, and C"** although A, B, and C are very different? I'm not sure if I can group different things together (I think someone said it is okay to say "this here is your chair and desk" because a chair is very different from a desk, while you have to say "these are your coworkers," since you can't have more than one type of coworker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd vote for "Please take a look at the ones with **a check mark**" ("beside them" seems superfluous to me) unless each one has more than a single check mark.

I'd also vote for "I've attached (the) **copies of the photos**", unless there is only a single document that contains copies of all the photos.

This kind of number concord often causes a problem, e.g.,

> They all nodded their head  [One head with many bodies?]

or

> They all nodded their heads  [Each body a [hydra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernaean_Hydra) (a multiheaded beast)?]

or what? A fan of the singular "they/their/them" might suggest something like this:

> Everyone nodded their head.

Sometimes English is intrinsically awkward.

Comment: I agree the first two examples both sound ambiguous, but I believe one of them must be academically correct. The second one (heads) I guess.

Comment: @NS.X.: In the sexist old days, of course, we'd have said "Everyone nodded **his** head" (unless they were all female, in which case it'd be "**her** head"). I'd probably accept "**Everyone** nodded **their** head" even though I'm not a fan of the usage: its meaning is clear with "everyone".

Comment: @Bill Franke: I've made some edits to my original question. Can you please help?

Comment: @jess: Yes, you can say "**Please find attached the copies of A, B, and C**". They're all copies that the receiver of the email requested you send, so they all belong to the same category. An easier sentence, perhaps, is "**Attached are the copies of A, B, and C that you requested**" or "**Copies of A, B, and C are attached**". Email should be brief & to the point, & to colleagues & coworkers it can be informal, polite, & respectful (2nd & 3rd sentences), but when it's to a superior in your or some other organization, it needs to be more formal (1st sentence), of course.

Comment: @Bill Franke: Ooh, thank you for the distinction between formal and informal sentences. I wonder if "these are your chair and desk" is as correct as "this here is your chair and desk" (from http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6612/making-phone-calls-with-someone). Is here a reason I should say one thing over the other? Also, can you say "the copies **for** A, B, and C"?

Comment: @jess:  "_This here is your chair and desk_" is substandard colloquial English because of **this here**. It'd have to be "_This is your chair and desk_" (one piece of furniture) or "_These are your chair and desk_" (two pieces) or "_{This is / These are} your chair and desk, here_". In spoken English, "_{This, **here**, is / These , **here**, are} your chair and desk_" is possible because of the pauses (commas) and stress (**bold font**). "The copies **for** A, B, and C" imples that the attached copies are going to three different people or offices or other places. Use **of**.

Comment: Can I use **for** in this situation? "where are my invoices **for** orders A, B, and C?" And when I'm asking for someone/people, can I say either? "Are A & B there" (to stress that they are two different people) "Is A & B there?" (to stress that they are family/couples?).

Comment: @jess: You can say **for orders A, B, and C** if they're three different orders (but can be orders for the same item). You have to say **Are A & B there?** even if they're conjoined twins like [Chang & Eng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang_and_Eng_Bunker), because they're two different people & because the subject is grammatically plural, so the verb has to agree with it, eg: "{Are Mr & Mrs Jones / Are the Joneses} there?". But you can say either "{Is / Are} the Jones family there?"