# Using Plural word with the conjunction "And"

Tags: sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

Which one of the below is wrong and why?

1. We get values **for possibilities** X and Y.
2. We get values  **for possibility of** X and Y.
3. We get values  **for possibilities of** X and Y.

The question has some similarities but more specific than  [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5405/using-plural-nouns-with-plural-nouns). My focus is on how should I write **for possibility(ies of)**.

Edit:

X and Y are just arbitrary object for demonstration purpose.

Comment: [More information would be helpful](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), as the answer may differ depending on what X and Y are. Please also include efforts you have made to answer the question and what _you_ think the answer might be.

Comment: @fred2  X and Y are just arbitrary object for demonstration purpose, I have edited the post.

Comment: By "possibility", do you mean "probability"?

Comment: @rjpond that is correct, aren't both interchangeable?

Comment: English speakers do sometimes say "possibility" when they mean "probability".  But it seems like this is a fairly technical piece of writing and it would be a lot clearer to say "probability".  I would probably go for (3) "the probabilities of X and Y", since if you say "the probability of X and Y", it might sound as though you mean the probability of both happening simultaneously.

Comment: @rjpond thank you, could you pleas tell what is wrong with 1?

Comment: It depends.  If X and Y are the names of the conditions/events whose probabilities you're measuring, it's "the probabilities of X and Y".  But X and Y are the names of the probabilities of those events occurring, it's "the probabilities X and Y".  (Whether X and Y can acceptably double up as the names for both the events themselves and the probabilities of their occurrence, I'm not sure - statistics isn't really my area.)

Comment: I don't like the example context. Try thinking about something structurally similar, such as *We **watched** [the] **movie / movies** Psycho and Goodfellas*. In which case the question might simply disappear anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

3 is *probably* closest to what you want, but you need to add a definite article.

> **We get the values for the possibilities of X and Y.**

---

**Long answer:**

However, all your examples could be right, or nearly right, in different contexts, so it's not really possible to answer your question with certainty. I also wonder if you mean probability, not possibility. Possibilities don't have literal values, whereas probabilities do.

Are X and Y literally possibilities/probabilities themselves? If yes, you could say this:

> We obtained values of probabilities X and Y. X is 10% and Y is 50%.

I appreciate you probably don't mean X and Y to be literally interpreted as names for probabilities, but if they were, then your option 1 works.

I think 2 is least likely to ever make sense as a choice. You need an article, and the number needs to change, but you could have a compound phrase of some sort where the singular form worked:

> We obtained **the** value **of the** probability of thunder and lightning later that day.

In this case the probability (singular) refers to the probability of things which are considered part of the same (singular) phenomenon (namely, "thunder and lightning").

3 needs an article

> We obtained **the** values **of the** probabilities of rain and sunshine.

'Rain and sunshine' are separate probabilities unlikely to be seen together, so plural makes sense.

Note you can replace 'of the' with 'for the', and that again changes how articles can be used.

> We obtained values **for** probabilities X and Y.

> We obtained **the/a** value **for the** probability of thunder and lightning later that day.

> We obtained values **for the** probabilities of rain and sunshine.

So ... the strict answer to your question is "it is highly dependent on context".